# Problems displaying international characters in Canvas using fillText

Tags: canvas, character

I am trying to write French characters (e.g. é) out to the canvas using filltext() and failing. 
The text just displays with the white-filled diamond and question mark "?" in the centre.
All other "English" characters display normally.

My page is marked up as:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
<title> Title </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

and I am using the Arial font.
My browser is Firefox 10.0 on the Desktop and the Default browser on an HTC Desire HD.

My code for writing the text is:

```
context.font = "normal 16px Arial, Sans-Serif";
context.fillText('Mission Echouée', x, y);
```

I should add that this has worked for me in the past. Possibly about 5 months ago.

Does anyone have any insight / experience for me ?

Many thanks
Mark

Comment: Are you sure, your font setting is working properly?

Answer (score 1):

Just found this old ticket so wanted to provide the answer.
I should have clarified that I was actually including the translated text data like this:

```
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="script/textdata.js"></script>
```

The problem was that the textdata.js file was not saved as UTF-8
Once saved as UTF-8 the international characters display correct.

Answer (score 0):

Something else has to be going on here. Simplify your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/kHqmP/

That fiddle works fine for me in the latest chrome, firefox and IE9 on Windows 7. It also works on my Galaxy Nexus.

Does it not work for you?

I imagine its something that you are setting unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Simon.
The issue appeared to be with my copying and pasting the é character from Gmail. 
When I generated the character myself it worked fine.

Although I've no idea why this should be it actually works so I'm going to forget there was ever a problem :)